# Pass java map from JSTL/JSP to JavaScript methods

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp

We have couple of related drop downs where results of one drop down relate to other dropdown.

We have a mapping defined for what to select when in the form of map-of-map, like this;

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> topics = new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>();
        Map<String,String> ds = new HashMap<String, String>();
        ds.put("Array", "Array");
        ds.put("LL", "LL");
        topics.put("DS",  ds);
        Map<String,String> algo = new HashMap<String, String>();
        algo.put("BS", "BS");
        algo.put("Sorting", "Sorting");
        topics.put("Algorithm", algo);

        Map<String,String> phil = new HashMap<String, String>();
        phil.put("phil1", "phil1");
        phil.put("phil2", "phil2");
        topics.put("Philosophy",  phil);

        Map<String,String> others = new HashMap<String, String>();
        others.put("others", "others");
        topics.put("Others", others);
```

As per the above map, when "DS"is selected, we want to display  "Ärray"and "LL". Similar is the case with other mappings.

I pass this map to JSP and use JSTL to render the options. While making decision to call JS to populate subsequent drop-down, I want to change it to JSON.

I want to pass specific map of the selected option to the JS method and populate subsequent drop down.

Is converting to JSON the only way? If yes, how about passing it from the controller? If we don't pass it from the controller, what are the cleaner ways to do it in JSP itself?

JSP Block is as follows:

```
<div>Subject</div>
        <select name="topic"  onchange="callJavaScriptMethodWithMapOfSelectedComponent(mapOfSelectedValue)");">
            <c:forEach var="entry" items="${topics}">
                    <option value="${entry.key}">${entry.key}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
<select name="college">
                    <option value="default">Select Subject</option>
           </select>
```

Depending on the values selected in first drop down, we need to populatevalues in second drop down.

JS method would take map of selected value in first drop down and populate second one.

```
  function setOptions(chosen) {
var selbox = document.myform.college;

selbox.options.length = 0;
if (chosen == " ") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options above first',' ');

}
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('//Choosen from the map passed','oneone');

}

}
```

Comment: why are you using a hashmap when the key and value are the same ?

Comment: This is just an example and I could have things (ex. subject code along with the name)

Comment: Did you able to solve it, I too need same implementation.

Answer (score 0):

First off I think you better change it so that topics is a Map < String, List < String > >, that'd make more sense since it's a single depth hierarchy.

Next up you  have the choice of either converting the map into JSON and using eval to fill an object in javascript, or manually transverse the map keys and add them to the object, it all depends on the tools you have at hand to serialize the map into JSON server side (You can use new JSONObject(topics); from json.org) then just eval the json into a variable on Javascript.

Comment: If you already solved it , please explain the implementation.